# How good a knowledge of a language does one need to roleplay/GM in it?

Tags: finding-other-players

I was born in Finland. I've now lived in Denmark, capital region, for less than a year. I am about to move to Norway, not capital region. English is not the native language of any of these countries.

In Denmark I have found sufficient English-speaking roleplayers to play with. English is not my native language, and neither it is the native language of any of the players, but we have all been sufficiently fluent to play with few problems. Maybe a couple of times a session I forget some English word, and then explain my way around it; good enough for me. I am reasonably fluent in English, and have been for quite some time before roleplaying in the language.

In Norway, outside the capital region, it might not be so trivial to find people willing to roleplay in English. The languages of Denmark and Norway are closely related, so I will learn bokmål Norwegian with reasonable speed, I guess. But roleplaying is a pretty demanding activity.

I'm looking for experiences of people who have played or ran roleplaying games in their non-native language. **What kinds of signs tell you that you are ready to roleplay/GM in a foreign language?**

Comment: I think this answer would be improved if it described what a good answer might look like. For example, personal anecdotes don’t seem like they’d be all that helpful—see the people who voted to close this as primarily opinion-based. The fact that someone from X with knowledge of Y managed to GM (or failed to GM) in language Z after N months doesn’t really help you with A, B, and C. For that matter, how to even measure fluency seems challenging. It also might help (though it’s understandable if you don’t want to) to actually name A, B, and C, since it’s really hard to be generic here.

Comment: I think it may be difficult to explain what signs of readiness to look for, because that might differ from person to person. So, it looks like the community thinks this is opinion-based. There might be ways to rephrase it to be less opinion-based, but I myself am not sure how. Maybe instead of asking for ways to identify if you/someone is ready, ask for the specific language skills that are helpful?

Comment: @Bloodcinder I figured the specific language skills would be a separate question.

Comment: I think this revision will help if the question is reopened to get a European perspective. I don't think the specific languages involved would warrant a different question. Now we need to figure out how to make this more answerable without being opinion-based.